# Why i'm not getting the FPSController Rotation values?

Tags: unity, c#

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityStandardAssets.Characters.FirstPerson;

public class RotateObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    public UnityStandardAssets.ImageEffects.Blur blur;
    public UnityStandardAssets.ImageEffects.BlurOptimized blurOptimized;
    public FadeScript fadescript;
    [SerializeField] Quaternion targetRotation;    /// <summary>Rotation you want to achieve.</summary>
    [SerializeField] private float s;       /// <summary>Rotation duration.</summary>
    private Quaternion initialRotation;     /// <summary>Your GameObject's initial rotation.</summary>
    private float t;                        /// <summary>Your 't' reference.</summary>
    private FirstPersonController fpcscript;


    void Awake()
    {
        fpcscript.enabled = false;
        fpcscript = transform.GetComponent<FirstPersonController>();
        initialRotation = transform.localRotation;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (fadescript.alphaZero == true)
        {
            if (t < 1.0f)
            {
                transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(initialRotation, targetRotation, t);
                t += (Time.deltaTime / s); /// Each 60 frames [optimally] t reaches 1, divided by your duration, it will reach 1 on 'x' seconds.
            }
            else /// Your rotation ends here:
            { /// reset 't' [if you please], and reset 'initialRotation' 
                initialRotation = transform.rotation;

                blur.enabled = false;
                blurOptimized.enabled = false;
                fpcscript.enabled = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The script is attached to FPSController.
In the Inspector the Rotation of the FPSController is: X = 7 Y = 112 Z = -31

But when i'm using a break point on the line in the Awake:

```
initialRotation = transform.localRotation;
```

I see that initialRotation values are: (-0.2, 0.8, -0.2, 0.5)

What i want to do is to rotate the transofrm from X = 7 Y = 112 Z = -31 to rotation 0,0,0
That is why i also didn't set any values to targetRotation since i want it to rotate to 0,0,0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values that the Log throws you are of a Quaternion, which is a matrix of 4 components **{ x, y, z, w }**, if you would like to Log your Quaternion in an Euler (x, y, z) format, Log **transform.eulerAngles** instead.

For the next point, if you want to set the rotation to Euler(0, 0, 0) you can either:

- Use Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, 0f);
- Use Quaternion.identity

And assign that rotation to the Lerp.

```
    void Awake()
    {
        fpcscript.enabled = false;
        fpcscript = transform.GetComponent<FirstPersonController>();
        initialRotation = transform.localRotation;

        Debug.Log("Rotation on Euler format is: " + transform.eulerAngles);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (fadescript.alphaZero == true)
        {
            if (t < 1.0f)
            {
                transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(initialRotation, Quaternion.identity, t);
                t += (Time.deltaTime / s); /// Each 60 frames [optimally] t reaches 1, divided by your duration, it will reach 1 on 'x' seconds.
            }
            else /// Your rotation ends here, so you reached Euler(0, 0, 0).
            { /// reset 't' [if you please], and reset 'initialRotation' 
                initialRotation = transform.rotation;

                blur.enabled = false;
                blurOptimized.enabled = false;
                fpcscript.enabled = true;
            }
        }
    }
```